# Click "OK" on Javascript AlertDialog box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, modal-dialog, alert

I'm trying to automatically click on "Yes" on a Javascript AlertDialog box (yes/no) but I can't catch the "popup" window.
Here is my try :

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2;

protected void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_rptSystemHistory_ctl01_lnkDelRequest");
        elementButton.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: do it inside a JavaScript

Comment: @MethodMan What do you mean?

Comment: Why would you want to click on an alert dialog for the user?  That is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: You can't do it at all, not possible.  The javascript alert box requires user interaction.  The only thing you could do would be to write a chrome, IE, FireFox, and Safari extension/addon and have the addon do it.  Which would be dev for 4+ browsers and 3 operating system.  So basically impossible (time constraint wise)

Comment: I'm trying to delete multiple information at once so the user just have to click on "Launch program" and the software will do all the stuff.

When I delete something, an alertbox "are you sure?" appears. So I want to hide this part for the user and handle this with my program.

Comment: "Launch program" is something that is part of the browser (Sounds like you are using Firefox maybe).  You cannot control this in javascript unfortunately.  You may want to think about another way to do this.

Comment: @user3206787 what do you mean `What do I mean...?` are you serious..??

Comment: @MethodMan and others - the OP is working with embedded browser control in a winforms application. Although alert dialog box cannot be dismissed by means of javascript, it may be entirely possible to detect the dialog presence and dispatch a keyboard event to close it in a desktop winforms application.

Comment: @Igor I am pretty clear on what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

You cannot click yes on a alert dialog via javascript.  It is handled by the browser and is not part of the DOM